# Visual Studio 2010 SharePoint Replaceable Parameter is not being replaced

Tags: wcf, visual-studio-2010, sharepoint-2010

I'm creating a custom WCF service for deployment inside SharePoint 2010 following the [instructions](http://www.sharepointbits.com/blog/custom-wcf-services-in-sharepoint-2010.html) on the SharePoint Bits Blog.

As step 3 says, I am building contents of my .SVC file.  Note that this is a blank text file with a .SVC extension, and I have manually entered the text into this file.

```
<%@ ServiceHost 
Language="C#" 
Factory="...(omited for length)..."
Service="Assembly.MyService, $SharePoint.Project.AssemblyFullName$" %>
```

The `$SharePoint.Project.AssemblyFullName$` is a [replaceable parameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee231545.aspx) that visual studio is supposed to replace with the strong name of the assembly built by my project when the solution is packaged.

The problem is that the replaceable parameter isn't getting replaced during the package step.  My project also includes a visual web part (the .webpart file of which contains the same replaceable parameter) that is having its replaceable parameter replaced correctly.

how do I get the replaceable parameter in my .SVC file to replace during the package step?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you added .SVC file extension to this list:

> Although tokens can theoretically be
>   used by any file that belongs to a
>   SharePoint project item included in
>   the package, by default, Visual Studio
>   searches for tokens only in package
>   files, manifest files, and files that
>   have the following extensions:
>
> XML
>
> ASCX
>
> ASPX
>
> Webpart
>
> DWP
>
> These extensions are defined by the
>   
>   element in the
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.SharePoint.targets
>   file, located in the …\\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\SharePointTools
>   folder.
>
> You can, however, add additional file
>   extensions to the list. To do this,
>   add a 
>   element to any PropertyGroup in the
>   SharePoint project file that is
>   defined before the  of the
>   SharePoint targets file.

Comment: DOH!  I apparently skipped right over that part of the article without noticing.  That did it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

Preferred option is to add a new `PropertyGroup` to the `Project.csproj` file manually in Notepad (aaargh), but then at least it works on a fresh checkout / other dev pc as well:

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TokenReplacementFileExtensions>svc</TokenReplacementFileExtensions>
  </PropertyGroup>
```